# can you do a query such as mysql query in JSON data

Tags: mysql, json

Say that I have a json data, from the table I have from my database, it's just in a json format.

Can you actually do a query to a json data ?
We use "select * from from tbtest" in mysql, is there any query in json ?

If it is possible to do a query to a json data, can I do complicated query such as inner join,left join,right join, where clauses and etc.

Sorry for my bad english

Thank you! Really appreciate your help!

Comment: mysql 5.7 has JSON data structure and you can do query on JSON data https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use JSON data like that, you might as well use something like MongoDB which stores the data in BSON format, which is fairly similar to JSON.

As of MySQL 5.7 you have [JSON data types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) which can also be used for what you want.

```
mysql> SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('{"id": 14, "name": "Aztalan"}', '$.name');
```